# Variance safety in C#

Tags: c#, variance

I believe that there is a little mistake on this part of C# documentation! But i'm not sure. Is it really a documentation mistake? or maybe am i wrong?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/interfaces#variance-safety

**instead of:**

> Xi is contravariant or invariant and Ai is input-safe.

**it should be:**

> Xi is contravariant or invariant and Ai is input-UNsafe.

```
// test code 1
interface I1<out T>{ // T is covariant -> input-UNsafe

    I2<T> test1(); // error, I2<T> is output-unsafe! which proves my point
}
interface I2<in P> { } // P is contravariant!
```

I am using Visual Studio 16.7.2, Console App (.Net Framework) C# 7.3

Comment: If you have found a mistake in the documentation, just make a github post and they will likely fix it (after debating it for about 5 years and linking it to every 300 other discussions)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: my question is "is it really a documentation mistake? or maybe am i wrong?"

Comment: @jameslee Then you should add that [into the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63480764/edit). Right now, it just seems like you're reporting a mistake (to the wrong website).

Comment: @41686d6564 sorry, i'll fix that!

Comment: @MichaelRandall Thanks for your advice. I made a github post. So can you explain why the documentation is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in the C# 6 draft standard (which is currently published on learn.microsoft.com).  It has been fixed as part of the standardization process. You can see that in the official [C# 5.0 Standard](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-334.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

You are right, it's most likely an error in the documentation.

In addition to the chain of reasoning in your question, which makes perfect sense, I have another (intuitive) argument in favor of this being an error:

Let's compare the last two lines of the definition of **output-unsafe** (A):

> - Xi is covariant or invariant and Ai is output-unsafe.
> - Xi is contravariant or invariant and Ai is input-safe.

with the last two lines of the definition of **input-unsafe** (B):

> - Xi is covariant or invariant and Ai is input-unsafe.
> - Xi is contravariant or invariant and Ai is output-unsafe.

Input and output safety (as well as co- and contravariance) are symmetric in C#. Thus, those two definitions should be symmetric as well, but they aren't:

```
              A              B         
Line 1  "output-unsafe" "input-unsafe"
Line 2  "input-safe"    "output-unsafe"
               ^
               |
               +--- strange outlier
```

Your proposed correction would fix that as well.